# Symbolic math equation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to enter an equation into MATLAB which contains about 5 variables. Here is what I did:

```
syms Pwf Pr Qo J Qmax
Pwf = Pr((1.266 - (1.25*Qo/Qmax))^2) - 0.125
```

I want to run it such that I can input different values for different variables per time, but it gives an error:

> Invalid indexing or function definition.

How should I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Is the first operation a multiplication, i.e. `Pr * (...)`? If so, you *have* to write the `*`, otherwise MATLAB interprets this as either a function call or matrix indexing.

Comment: Thank you hbaderts. That works...but how do I now input the values?

Comment: do you want to just assign values to the variables ? Do I understand you correct? so you can write syms= 15; Pr=2; ... , if I get you wrong explain more detailed what you actually want!

Comment: Hello KiW: I want to assign values for Qo PR and Qmax...so I can get solution for Pwf. I tried something like Q=sym(1200) but it returned error

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are trying to create a function called `Pwf` which varies with respect to the values of `Pr`, `Qo` and `Qmax`

If  that's the case, you can use `syms` command in MATLAB to create a symbolic function Pwf with independent variables `Pr`, `Qo` and `Qmax`

```
syms Pwf(Pr, Qo, Qmax)
Pwf(Pr,Qo,Qmax) = Pr*((1.266 - (1.25*Q0./Qmax))^2) - 0.125;
```

This creates a symbolic function `Pwf` and sumbolic variables `Pr`, `Qo` and `Qmax`. You can then assign different values for the variables and call the function `Pwf`

```
Pr = 1; 
Qo = 2;
Qmax = 10; 
Pwf(Pr, Qo, Qmax)
```

This would yield you a result in fractions as follows.

```
ans = 113407/125000
```

You can get numeric output using `double()` or `vpa()`

```
>> vpa(ans)
ans = 0.907256

>> double(ans)
ans = 0.9073
```

You have mentioned about another variable `J` which is not used in the equation, which can be added in to the function in a similar way. You just have to call the function `Pwf(Pr, Qo, Qmax)` each time you change the variable values.